# Link docker container to external public IP

Tags: docker

On performing `curl ifconfig.me` on my machine I am able to get my public IP but the same does not works in my container.

Comment: I am able to ping ifconfig.me in container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer to my silly question is, we don't need to. Instead port binding is use to bind the container port to the system.
The public IP of system could be used with port to interact with hosted application.
Silly me!